# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string for my MYSQL Database

Tags: python, navicat

I have researched this question and I know what's wrong, it's just that I don't know how to reformat the "%s", sorry I am new to python.

```
@app.route("/edit_camera", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def editcamera():
    camera_id = request.args.get('id')# get the id parameter value
    connection=create_connection()
    if request.method =="POST":
        get = request.form
        Company = get["Company"]
        Model = get["Model"]
        PurchaseDate = get["PurchaseDate"]
        Condition = get["Condition"]
        KitLens = get["KitLens"]
        PurchasePrice = get["PurchasePrice"]

        #picture=
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Update record
                update_sql = "UPDATE tblcameras SET tblcameras.Company = %s,tblcameras.Model=%s,tblcameras.PurchaseDate=%s,tblcameras.Condition=%s,tblcameras.KitLens=%s,tblcameras.PurchasePrice=%s WHERE cameras.CameraID = %s"
                values=(Company,Model,camera_id)
                cursor.execute(update_sql,(values))
                #save or commit values in dbase
                connection.commit()
                cursor.close()
                return redirect("/cameras")
    return render_template("camera.html", title ="Editing New camera")
```

Answer (score -1):

pls try this,

```
    update_sql = "UPDATE tblcameras SET tblcameras.Company = '%s',tblcameras.Model='%s',tblcameras.PurchaseDate='%s',tblcameras.Condition='%s',tblcameras.KitLens='%s',tblcameras.PurchasePrice='%s' WHERE cameras.CameraID = '%s'"
    values=(Company,Model,PurchaseDate,Condition,KitLens,PurchasePrice,camera_id)
    cursor.execute(update_sql,(values))
```